# "Realm is not defined" when remote js debugging in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

When I open my app, Realm works fine, it opens an instance and I logged an area to return a console.log('Realm is opened') to check if the realm is being instantiated.

However, when I try to use React Native's remote js debugger, the app gets stuck at the login screen and says Realm is not defined.

When I debug the issue, it fails to do Realm.open(my object schema) and gives the error stated above.

I'm wondering if maybe it's an issue with chrome debugger's compatibility with realm or a separate issue entirely.

Comment: did u get solution for above?

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this issue. I realized that it is not due to chrome debugger by doing the following.

1. Used another browser
2. Used flipper

When using flipper I did not get the Realm is undefined but the instance of the realm returned an empty object i.e "{}"

My react-native version 0.64.2
realm version 10.6.1

The same code base works for the previous rn version. This is not a solution but maybe this will help in reproducing and resolving

Comment: Yours is not really an answer to the question, but please update it once you find a solution. - I will just follow the discussion, as I have observed some problems with debugging Realm as well, but I am not sure, if its the same as what you are describing.

Comment: Yes sure. Now I am planning to downgrade rn version to 0.63.0 as I have the same code base with this version and in that, I don't have this issue.

Comment: Hello, I downgraded the app to 0.63.0, but no luck. It did not make any changes. I then realized that it was indeed my code that was causing this issue. I was trying to update a row, without adding it to the realm in the first place. Updating non-existent data was my cause. Maybe this helps the OP.